# Having trouble creating a regex for a list of zip codes

Tags: regex

I need to test whether a list of zip codes in a textarea has **only** 5-digit zip codes. Under normal circumstances the list would look like this:

```
56228, 56243, 55324, 55325, 55329, 55355, 55389
```

I need to find out if there is anything but the above pattern in the textarea. There can be any number of individual zip codes, but I need to make sure there isn't anything else. (I think I'm going to need to be able to highlight illegal matches in the textarea also, but I'll cross that bridge when I get to it).

I started with this regex:

```
^\d{5},?\s?$+
```

I'm very new to building regular expressions, but as I understand it, the above should match any set of 5 digits, and commas and whitespace after the five digits may or may not be there.

Online regex testers (I've tried several) aren't finding any matches, whether I have a legitimate list of zip codes or a list with "illegal" characters.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your regex matches beginning-of-string, then 5 digits, then 0 or 1 comma, then 0 or 1 whitespace character, then 1 or more end-of-strings (this bit makes no sense: you can't have multiple ends in a string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^([, ]*\d{5})+[, ]*$
```

Comment: In a regex tester this worked on a list of valid zip code like in my OP, but when I removed a space or added letters, etc as in "02816, as123, 56, 02817,02889, 02893, 12345", I got "No matches" (There are 5 valid zip codes in there.)

Comment: Okay, that's not working the way I was thinking, so I'm probably being unclear. Sorry. For now I'm going to forget the highlighting and just find out if the string of zip codes is or is not valid. This can be a valid list: "02816, 02817,02889 02893," I need to make sure that the list has sets of 5 digits, separated by either a comma only, one or more spaces only, or both. And can also have trailing or leading commas or spaces. (I will be restricting the textarea to numbers, comma and space only). Again, I'm sorry if I'm being unclear (which I think I have been)

Comment: @eventide I've reedited to rematch your renew needs `;)` You can only have 5 digits now, just as you asked, i.e. `as123` and `56` won't match anymore. I you want them to match again, just replace the `\d{5}` by `[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,5}`. ZIP can be separated by spaces or commas.

Comment: this works as described. Thank you for your help (and patience).